# Gradle not satisfying dependencies?

Tags: gradle, wiremock

I'm trying to build this project from github:

https://github.com/tomakehurst/wiremock

The thing is, when I download it and run `gradle build`, I don't think all the required jar files are being loaded onto the class path. I get this error when I actually try to run the thing:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: joptsimple/OptionParser
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.standalone.CommandLineOptions.<init>(CommandLineOptions.java:75)
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.standalone.WireMockServerRunner.run(WireMockServerRunner.java:49)
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.standalone.WireMockServerRunner.main(WireMockServerRunner.java:110)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: joptsimple.OptionParser
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 3 more
```

What gives? Isn't grade supposed to have downloaded this dependency by itself?

Comment: if the gradle script is loading from a jar, it wont download the jar, you have to have the jar downloaded already and in the right folder

Comment: How are you running it after you've built it? ./gradlew build should work just fine. There's nothing special about that dependency.

Answer (score 1):

Try to execute `gradle clean build jarAll`

See [this github issue](https://github.com/tomakehurst/wiremock/issues/26) for reference

From what I see in the build code, the task jarAll handles the joptsimple classes (and various others)